# Get ID through input and redirect to page with this ID

Tags: php, html

everybody! I need your help or my head will blow up soon! I feel the solution is easy but...
When user enters ID and Date and clicks Submit button he must be redirected to the  devis.php page with the client id  entered before. Here is the initial code

```
<?php
include("db.php");

if( isset( $_REQUEST['submit'] ) )
{
$id=$_POST['client'];
$date=$_POST['calendar'];
?>

    <h1>IDENTITE CLIENT:</h1>
    <label>Client ID <input type="text" name="client" ></label>
    <br>
    <br>
    <label>Date de 1ere intervention <input type="date" name="calendar">    </label>
    <br>

<a href="devis.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>&date=<?php echo $date; ?>"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" ></a>
```

But in this code the inputs can be visible only after clicking Submit and if to get them out of php tags, the variable Id isn't recognised and no redirection is following.

Thank you for your help and time!

Comment: Do you want to do this in same page or two different pages

Comment: where is your form

Comment: Why do you have an input element inside an anchor tag? That looks like incorrect html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ADD THIS TO YOUR PHP CODE

```
if( isset( $_REQUEST['submit'] ) )
{
    $id=$_POST['client'];
    $date=$_POST['calendar'];
    header('location:devis.php?id='.$id.'&date='.$date);
}
```

And set form action attribute to blank `action=""`

Comment: This works for me! I removed header from the code as it didn't work right, but together with "action=devis.php" it works perfectly. Many thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is make a form like this:

```
   <form method = "POST" action = "devis.php">

    <h1>IDENTITE CLIENT:</h1>
    <label>Client ID <input type="text" name="client" ></label>
    <br>
    <br>
    <label>Date de 1ere intervention <input type="date" name="calendar">    </label>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" ></a>
    </form>
```

now in devis.php, you should be able to get the ID from previous page like this:

```
if ( isset($_POST['submit']) )
{
    $id = $_POST['client']; // ID inputted from the previous page.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a normal HTML form along with your required `inputs` inside `form` with `post` method and `action` with value `devis.php` since you want to redirected to `devis.php`

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="devis.php">
            <label>Client ID :</label><input type="text" name="client" ><br><br>
            <label>Date de 1ere intervention:</label> <input type="date" name="calendar"> <br><br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" >    
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Your `devis.php` page should do it. Here I am just `echo`-ing the values just to give you a clue of how to retrieve it. You can use it the way you want.

**devis.php**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["client"]){
        echo 'Client ID: '.$_POST["client"].'<br>';
    }
    if(isset($_POST["calendar"]){
        echo 'Date: '.$_POST["calendar"];
    }
?>
```

Comment: Yep, I forgot that "action" could redirect me to other page. I'll try it. Thx